# Tenho um código em vba que ao executar apresenta erro 438

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

```
Sub buscacep()

Range("B3:D3").ClearContents
    
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
ie.navigate "https://www.achecep.com.br/"
ie.Visible = True


Do While ie.busy And ie.readystate <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
DoEvents
Loop

ie.document.getElementByTagName("input")(0).Value = Cells(3, 2).Value

ie.document.getElementByClassName("botao")(0).Click

Do While ie.busy And ie.readystate <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

Esse é o código, mas não consigo achar o erro. E ao depurar, a linha que apresenta erro é:

```
ie.document.getElementByTagName("input")(0).Value = Cells(3, 2).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Tudo bem?

Acredito que você vai rir quando ler isso, mas não estava funcionando pois faltou um "s" em "getElementByTagName" e em "getElementByTagName".

O correto é:

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = Cells(3, 2).Value

ie.document.getElementsByClassName("botao")(0).Click
```

Ao alterar isso, funcionou normalmente.

Além disso, eu não sei como você insere dados na planilha em si, mas, para testar, eu desativei a linha para limpar o intervalo ("B3:D3") e digitei um CEP real qualquer, pois, sem valores na célula, retornou erro também.

Qualquer coisa, me avise aqui.